# Need to animate an object from one place to another in PowerPoint.

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to animate an object from one place to another in powerpoint. 
I can displace it between two points, but not more than that.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Scott thanks for your answer. I somehow got logged out and didn't see the answer notification. I am up-voting as well as accepting in few moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I just researched this in the past hour, so I’m far from expert,
and I don’t know whether I’m doing things the best way.
Most importantly, I’m not sure I’m doing the first step
(the one that you know how to do) the same way you’re doing it,
so this answer might not mesh with your existing practice.
Also, I’m working with PowerPoint 2013. That said,

- Create the object.
- On the “Animations” tab, in the “Advanced Animation” panel,
  click on the “Add Animation” button.
- Select “More Motion Paths…”.
- Select the “Down” line (corresponding to your illustration/example).
- Click on “OK”.

Now, I trust you’ve tried the next 5 steps.
(We normally ask people to describe what they’ve tried.)

- Click on the object again.
- Click on the “Add Animation” button.
- Select “More Motion Paths…”.
- Select the “Diagonal Down Right” line
  (again, corresponding to your illustration/example).
- Click on “OK”.

You should now have something that looks like this:

[image]

and when you animate it (i.e., preview it)
the arrow shape glides down from its starting position (upper left)
to the bottom of the first path,
then leaps back to the starting point
and slides down to the end of the second path (lower right).<sup>1</sup>

I guess this is the point at which you got stuck.

The next thing to do is to click on the second motion path:

[image]

and drag it down:

[image]

until the starting point of the second motion path (the upper left end)
coincides with the end of the first motion path
(the bottom of the line on the left):

[image]
This should now behave as you want.
Repeat the above steps for subsequent motions.

It may help you to click on “Animation Pane” in the “Advanced Animation” panel.
This gives you, obviously, the Animation Pane,
which is a section of the window to the right of the drawing. 
It lets you manipulate the individual animations (motions).

---

This [How to Animate Object Movements in PowerPoint](http://www.labnol.org/tech/animate-object-movements-in-powerpoint/12575)
page helped me figure this out.

---

<sup>1</sup> Why Microsoft thought that *this* was the correct default behavior
baffles me.